# <assume> a particular stance

Tags: word-meaning

> **Pose:** To pose is to **assume** a particular **stance**. Like a runway model strutting to the end of the catwalk, posing with her hands on her hips, and then gracefully walking back.
>
> [[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pose)]

I think "stance" means "the way that you're standing." And which definition does "assume" refer to here? (definition 3?): ['Assume' - Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/assume)

Comment: Idiomatically, we're [much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assume+a+particular+stance%2Cadopt+a+particular+stance&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) to (figuratively or literally) ***adopt** a stance* than to ***assume*** it. And that preference is far stronger in British English, where the latter is [virtually unknown](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assume+a+particular+stance%2Cadopt+a+particular+stance&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) (but still "comprehensible" - by context, if nothing else! :)

Comment: "assume" in such contexts is figuratively extended from [M-W's definition 6](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assume#:~:text=English%20Language%20Learners%20Definition%20of,in%20a%20job%20or%20situation) **PUT ON, DON**, which cites the example from Charlotte Brontë - *Mrs. Fairfax **assumed** her best black satin gown, her gloves, and her gold watch.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Hi, I've been thinking about the relationship between "adopt/assume a stance" and "put on/don".
But I still don't get it. Could you elaborate on it? Thanks!

Comment: You can (metaphorically) "put on" lots of things - [a deceptive smile / face / appearance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put+on+a+deceptive%22), for example. Think of it as like putting on a dress, for example, in a context where the ***appearance*** of the dress is what we're interested in. And note idiomatic usages like  [*He's just putting on an act*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22just+putting+on+an+act%22) (behaving / speaking in a false or artificial way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Longman's site that you cite does not really give a definition, but it is usage # 3. Furthermore, "stance" has multiple meanings. Its original meaning was "How one stood, posture." but it has also come to mean "opinion, viewpoint."

According to [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adopt%20the%20stance%2C%20assume%20the%20stance&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadopt%20the%20stance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassume%20the%20stance%3B%2Cc0), "adopt the stance" and "assume the stance" have only become commonly used in the last eighty years, and that, over those eighty years, "adopt the stance" has become more than twice as prevalent "as assume the stance."

However, "assume the position" has been more prevalent than "adopt the position" for over two hundred years

- [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adopt+the+position%2Cassume+the+position&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadopt%20the%20position%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassume%20the%20position%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cadopt%20the%20position%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassume%20the%20position%3B%2Cc0)

The results of ngram are never clear cut because you cannot determine whether its results show regional differences or properly reflect different contexts. It is just counting. The Bronte example, close to two hundred years old and from the north of England, sounds very unusual to my modern American ear.

Given this data on actual usage, imperfect as it is, I think we have to say that today  "assume the stance" is equivalent in meaning to "adopt the position."

Fowler said somewhere in his book on usage that some of the redundancies of the English language should be put to use. I'd suggest, at least if writing for an American audience, that you distinguish "adopt" as meaning "have come to agree with" and "assume" as meaning "accept provisionally or temporarily or conditionally or insincerely." That gets close to the more common meaning of "assume" and directly relates to the Bronte usage and to the weird way fashion models strut, which is not the way women walk normally.

Comment: I'm not gonna count 'em, but I wouldn't mind betting *most* written instances of [*"told to assume the position"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22told+to+assume+the+position%22) in Google Books will either be addressed to schoolboys about to be caned, or women about to be "rogered". Whatever - lets not forget that we routinely ask people ***where they stand*** in relation to issues of the day, as well as asking them what their stance or position might be. It's all very standard figurative usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think you are confusing the effect of the definite article with the meaning of the verb. "The artist told the model, 'Assume a position indicating extreme defiance"' carries no implication of imminent rogering or submitting to a thrashing. I would definitely use "assume" rather than "adopt" in that specific context. But I suspect that you and I agree that ngram is a tool of limited use: mere counting tells us only so much when it is divorced from context.

Comment: I might not put too much faith in NGrams if they don't agree with my preconceptions. But in this specific case, as flagged up in my first comment under the question, the NGram for *British* use of ***assume a particular stance*** draws a complete blank, which agrees with ***my*** stance. I thought you were UK-based, and would therefore reflect that same US/UK usage difference I subscribe to. Incidentally, the most common word for the broadest search term seems to be *adopt a **critical** stance* (where ***assume**,* which sounds decidedly "off" to me, doesn't chart at all for the BrE corpus).

Comment: "I might not put too much faith in NGrams if they don't agree with my preconceptions." Love it. Nope, never even visited the UK for as much as a day. A very provincial sort.

Comment: Well, it seems to me we often have [adopt? assume?!] the same position as regards the idiomacy of some particular turn of phrase, here on ELL. So it's always a bit of a surprise to me when we *don't*. But one thing I have learned here myself over the years is there's a lot more "legitimate" variety in language use than many people think. And these days, I lean increasingly to the *If it's comprehensible, it's legitimate* school of thought - the older I get, the more syntactic rules I see going on the bonfire of the vanities.

Comment: Yes, we do often agree, but I think that we were both probably well trained in "received English." The differences between the US version of "received written English"  and the UK version of "received written English" were minimal. I do not disagree that the schools today pay far less attention to "received English," which was a language of great subtlety and power. Students feel more comfortable, but learn a less powerful language.